# MySQL move data from one column to another column if data already exists in that column

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked through existing answers on this but can't seem to find the right one that fits, so:

I have a database populated by a php form that has a number of columns:

name | latest_figure | previous_figure1 | previous_figure2 | previous_figure3

I can update the table using a typical mysql query, but I need the data to move to the right on updating if data already exists in that field.

For example, if we have:

name=Lee, latest_figure=80

I now want to update the table with

name=Lee, latest_figure=85, I want the original figure of 80 to move into the column previous_figure1.

If we update the table again, and name=Lee has a latest_figure=88, I want the 85 to move to previous_figure1 and 80 to move to into previous_figure2, and so on.

The reason for the keeping of the data is for graphical reasons to show progress/deterioration etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're better of using a different database structure tbh more normalised so you may have a tblusers, tbldata.  tblusers containers UserID,UserName.  tbldata contains autoincrement ID column, UserID,Data  so then if you want to pull the data out for a user you simply do "SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE UserID=$userid ORDER BY ID DESC" for newest first.  If you want to do oldest first change DESC to ASC.  This format also allows you to store a much larger data set of data without needing to keep adding columns each time.  Look into Data Normalisation (with a z for yank spelling)

Comment: try `UPDATE table previous_figure3=previous_figure2, previous_figure2=previous_figure1, previous_figure1=latest_figure, latest_figure=85 WHERE name='Lee'`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rewrite your table. You should have a table that has:

name | figure | timestamp

Then you can always get the figures by name and order by timestamp so you know which is the latest. It's easier than alway making a new column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Dieter. Although I need to keep the old figures?

Comment: If you add a timestamp at the time you insert the new value, you will still keep the old value?

Comment: His way would work if you used GROUP BY name but its kinda a bad method of doing things.  What if people have the same name!

Comment: @Dave: true, but then you can work around with another table person and get a connection between person and figures.

Comment: see my comment on the op :)_

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I get the gist of what you're suggesting so will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use ON DUPLICATE KEY if primary key is set.

```
INSERT INTO table (name, latest_figure) VALUES("Lee", 85) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE previous_figure3 = previous_figure2, previous_figure2 = previous_figure1, previous_figure1 = latest_figure, latest_figure = 85;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I agree that you should rewrite your table though.